# Is there a list of css browser compatability

Tags: css, cross-browser, less

I am starting to use `Less` and i like the idea of creating Parametric Mixins to make my website cross browser compatible. For example:

```
.border-radius(@radius) {
    -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
    -moz-border-radius: @radius;
    border-radius: @radius;
}
```

Is there a list of these kind of mixins to include into my Less file structure? That way i can just use `.border-radius(5px)` all over my website and ill know its browser compatible throughout?

Comment: You should use a plugin for the compiler to solve this. That would be so much easier. Are you using some node plugin to compile less?

Comment: This website you can search the CSS tags and see what browsers support them. https://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Comment: @muecas the problem with that is we are using C# for our backend and angular.js for our front

Comment: Well, less files must be compiled in some way. Is angular tanking care of your less files? Thru webpack maybe?

Comment: @muecas Through WebCompiler Extension is Visual Studio 2017 https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the plugin you are using for Visual Studio, i recommend you to use the autoprefixer for less (included in the plugin). This way you will be able to write only the standard css property, and the autoprefixer will add all the vendor prefixes when compiling the less files.

According to the docs, you must include the `"AutoPrefix" : true` option in the configuration file of the WebCompiler extension:

```
[
  {
    "outputFile": "output/output.css",
    "inputFile": "input/input.less",
    // ...Your set of options and configurations
    "options":{
        // ...Your other options
        "AutoPrefix": true
    }
  }
]
```

Default values for `compilerconfig.json` can be found in the `compilerconfig.json.defaults` on your project configuration files or plugin specific configuration files.